# What would it look like inside a spherical mirrored room?

Tags: optics, reflection, mirror-symmetry

What would it look like if you were inside a perfectly spherical "room" that was completely mirrored (seamless) with a small, single source of light?

---

Previously I'd wondered/theorized about a cubic mirrored room, but got a basic impression after stumbling onto a related [Flikr album](https://flic.kr/s/aHsjx6ygRp):

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
*<sup>(Photos by [Ron Brinkmann](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ronbrinkmann/sets/72157628242004349/detail/), with permission)</sup>*

---

It seems like a sphere would appear fundamentally different, but how?

What would be the easiest way to find out?

Comment: Check out the YouTube channels Vsauce and Veritasium, I believe one of them covered the interior of a spherical room in a video.